# How to check if a pointer is null in python?

Tags: python, windows, pointers, python-3.x, ctypes

I need to process a pointer to get its value via a callback. This is problematic since this pointer is null during the first call. So doing a *pointer.contents* does *ValueError: NULL pointer access*. To avoid this, how to check if the pointer is null ?

Comment: Well you could just catch the ValueError, hard to give anymore advice than that with no code or context.

Comment: No need to post the code, I think you just gave a correct answer to the question :) thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

NULL Pointers have a boolean False value, so:

```
if pointer:
    x = pointer.contents
else:
    print "NULL pointer"
```

*Edited for indentation*

Comment: I missed to notice that in the documentation…

Answer (score -2):

Try this: http://pythoncentral.io/python-null-equivalent-none/ 
and go to "checking if a variable is none"

Comment: Actually, the pointer is not None, it's not a common python variable type. The pointer is said null when the pointed value does not exist.

Comment: @BogeyJammer, except Python doesn't have typed variables. It has names that are bound to objects, like tags. So it's enough to say that a pointer and `None` are different types. Note that ctypes will generally convert a `None` argument to a `NULL` pointer, and the simple pointer types (i.e. `c_void_p`, `c_char_p`, `c_wchar_p`) convert `NULL` to `None` when used as a function `restype` or as a field in a struct or union.

Comment: That doesn't work for all cases, though. If you specify a ctype function `restype` that is a pointer, and that function returns NULL, ctypes does not convert it to None (because the pointer variable is in your scope, it just happens to point to NULL) - you get a ctypes pointer object, so `x is None` will always be False.